# django signal wont work after adding a save function

Tags: django

I have a simple model like this:

```
class ScientificInfo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    info1 = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=SURVEY_CHOICES, blank=True)
    info2 = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=SURVEY_CHOICES, blank=True)
    info3 = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=SURVEY_CHOICES, blank=True)
    is_interviewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.info1:
            self.is_interviewed = 'True'
            super(ScientificInfo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Every time a user is added to the app, a ScientificInfo object will be created for it using this signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='save_new_user_survey')
def survey_create(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    user = instance
    if created:
        survey = ScientificInfo(user=user)
        survey.save()
```

everything worked fine until I added that save method inside my model. the method works but the signal is disabled. Can you guys help me? thanks

Comment: You only save `ScientificInfo` instances when `info1` is not blank

Comment: Move `super(ScientificInfo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` one tab to the left.

Answer (score 0):

I'm well sure that the following couldn't work at all:

```py
        survey = ScientificInfo(user=user)
        survey.save()
```

Fields `info1`, `info2`, `info3` haven't `default` values and they aren't `null=True` as well. Thus survey with these blank fields couldn't be saved to DB unless you fill them.

I'm not sure whether is it your problem, but if you need to fix it (I believe you do), you should add `null=True` to those 3 fields.